# How should a NavBar communicate with a Component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using 'react-native-router-flux' with my React Native app and I can't seem to figure out how my Custom Nav Bar should communicate with my component?

I have the following code.

NavigationRouter.js:

```
<Scene key='addDrillScreen' component={AddDrillScreen} navBar={AddDrillNavBar} />
```

AddDrillScreen.js:

```
class AddDrillScreen extends React.Component {
  performSave() {
    // Want to call performSave() when NavBar is clicked
  }

}
```

AddDrillNavBar.js:

```
class AddDrillNavBar extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.saveButton}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          // ??? How do I trigger the performSave() on my AddDrillScreen?
        }}>
          <Text style={styles.saveButtonText}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

I don't understand how the two communicate

Comment: Here is a similar issue. Hope this fixes your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846655/how-do-i-call-execute-a-function-from-another-component-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here

- Make `performSave` static
- Move `performSave` to a different class, one that could be shared and isn't a react component
- Use the best practice for this kind of action in your flux library if you use one. For instance, in `redux` you would have included that code in an action creator.